# Click event on parent firing on clild element

Tags: jquery

I have a click event on an element, but want to prevent firing it on clicking on child element (they have their own click event).  Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="mailholderwrap" data-msgid="813">
    <div class="from">John Smith</div>
    <div class="subject"><i class="fa fa-star mail_action_link"></i> This is test message subject</div>
    <div class="actions"><i class="fa fa-upload mail_action_link"></i><i class="fa fa-download mail_action_link"></i><i class="fa fa-eye mail_action_link"></i></div>
</div>
```

Those icons have their own click actions. The problem is they are not firing, instead the click event on `.mailholderwrap` is firing.  My jQuery code

```
$('.mailholderwrap').click(function() {
    var messageId = $(this).attr('data-msgid');
    console.log(messageId);
});
```

How do I exclude the class `mail_action_link` to execute it's own click event instead of its parent?  Thanks

Comment: It is because `mail_action_link` element hasn't any content to make it clickable. http://jsfiddle.net/vfhLbkqm/

Comment: @Mohammad It's clickable, the width and the height is set via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event bubbling inside your child click events check this [stoppropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$(".mail_action_link").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Won't this stop firing the element's own click event?

Comment: No , it will stop the event bubbling only for parent elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the target of the event to see which element was clicked. If it's not the parent, you can exit.

```
$('.mailholderwrap').on('click', evt => {
    if (!$(evt.target).is('.mailholderwrap')) return; //<-- allow only on parent
    var messageId = $(this).attr('data-msgid');
    console.log(messageId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation() Like so

```
$('.mail_action_link').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
});
```